# What's the correct transliteration of ~"yao mae"?

Tags: spelling

I've heard a martial arts Sensei use a phrase that sounds to my English ears like "yow may", I think in context (at the end of a teaching, when it was time to practice he would clap his hands and then say this) meaning something like "let's go" or "to the front".  What's the proper/standard spelling of this phrase when you transliterate it to Latin characters?

Comment: If it were something that was said *after* the practice, it would be "yame" (止め), meaning "Stop!", "Avast!".

Comment: Are you sure it's even a Japanese martial art?

Comment: @naruto I was pretty sure it was before, but maybe I'm remembering wrong.  Thanks for the insightful comment either way.

Comment: @istrasci, yes, it's Aikido.  :)

Comment: @naruto also love the "avast!" translation :)

Comment: @naruto is it possible someone (especially a non-native speaker) would say it when done teaching, in the sense of "OK, that's enough, I'm done talking"?  My partner also remembers him saying it at the end of teaching rather than at the end of practicing, that's why I wonder about the above possibility.  (I know, maybe we're both remembering wrongly.)

Comment: Whoever upvoted istrasci's comment after mine...is there more to the "are you sure?" than my surface interpretation of it?

Comment: Was your sensei actually Japanese, or did they just (mis)remember the phrase themselves?

Comment: @deceze No, not native Japanese.  Used frequently enough that I don't think it would be a misremember on their part, though.

Comment: はじめ (Hajime) sounds most correct from the context. A teacher would say this to let students start solving problems in an exam or to let students start practicing in PE. やめ (Yame) is the just opposite.

Comment: @KeitaODA thanks, that rings a bell too.  Maybe I was confusing the two, and he'd say Yame at the end, Hajime at the beginning of the physical part.

Comment: BTW why was my question downvoted?  Also why do people answer in comments here?  :)

Comment: It just seems like a poorly defined question, possibly unanswerable. People can only make guesses.

Comment: @snailplane fair enough, I guess it seemed better defined when I was more sure what I was remembering.  Nonetheless I think it's been fruitful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you are referring to does indeed sound like (止め) or Yame!!** 
A lot times (止め) or "stop", is used in some sort of practice like baseball (少年野球) ,budou (武道) and other sports.

In a competition, Judo for example this is what is said.

> Before initial match. 『まて』、『そのまま』  『Wait』、『stay』
>
> Re-start of match and during the match. 『はじめ』, 『よし』 『Start』, 『resume』
>
> At the end of the match 『それまで』   『Stop』Not the literal translation,
>   that would be 『Until then or the end』

Although  (止め) is used quite a lot during pratice it is not said in a tournament.

Not sure if that helps you any?

Answer (score 0):

As naruto said, it could be "yame" (止め), meaning "Stop!", "Avast!".  I disagree that it would have to be after the practice to make sense.  Having no other suggestions I will go with this.

Comment: Why do you disagree?

Comment: @Nothingatall because I think it also could make sense before the practice, because that's where Sensai is ending his teaching.  I.e. "That's enough talking, let's practice!"

Comment: It's a command to stop, not an announcement of stopping.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand this before.  Thanks!